# Is it possible to remove references to System.Web.UI.*?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This may be a dumb question, but is it possible to remove references to `System.Web.UI.*`? For example, my application has two custom classes that are called `Panel` and `Control`, but I can't refer to them as such in the code because they conflict with the classes in `System.Web.UI`.

Since I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC environment, I won't have a need for the controls provided in that namespace, so it would be wonderful if I can remove references to it so I can type the *short-hand* references to my classes.

If it matters, it's a ASP.NET MVC 2 .NET 4 application.

Comment: Shouldn't removing the using clause for `System.Web.UI` from your code files be enough?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be smarter to re-think your own class names to avoid conflicts?  I've created panel controls with extended features, and named them appropriately (example: SurveySectionPanel).  Even Microsoft does this with the TextBox and MaskedTextBox (WinForms controls, not ASP.NET, but it still makes the point.)  If you don't want to do that, then just refer to your full class name starting from the root namespace.  You can refer to yours as the YuorNamespace.HoweverManyLevelsDeepYou'veNestedIt.Panel

Comment: @David, I know what you mean I was just trying to see if it's possible to bypass it. I wanted to keep the controls named after the CSS classes they are styled by. Oh, well, guess it can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. You can remove references to assemblies, but not namespaces. They are part of the System.Web assembly, which you need for a web application. I'd recommend refactoring your controls to have different names.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare synonyms to namespaces.

```
using DotNetControls= System.Web.UI.*;
```

And just don't use `DotNetControls`.
I think You can also use code snippets to declare for example that `panel` will become `MyNamespace.Panel`